# Saving an array of images as PFFiles

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

Is it possible to save an array of images under one field-name in mlab.com/heroku running Parse Server. I'm trying to save 150 images in one field-name. I know how to save one image. But is it possible to save 150+ in one field-name.

Comment: Are you using Parse Server?  I may have assumed so without asking.

Comment: yes I am Would your solution still work

Comment: Hey frankie. What do you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save an array of 'images', as in `PFFiles`, but you can save an array of `PFObjects`.  So create an array of `PFObjects`, each with the same class name, each with a `PFFile` assigned to the same field name in that `PFObject`, then save like so:

```
PFObject.saveAll(inBackground: myObjects, block: { result, error in

})
```

Then you'll also be able to retrieve all those files as well via retrieving the `PFObjects`

**EDIT**

Here is a quick sloppy example of how you might get started:

```
    let objectA = PFObject(className: "Some")
    objectsA["thumbnail"] = myPFFile1

    let objectB = PFObject(className: "Some")
    objectsB["thumbnail"] = myPFFile2

    PFObject.saveAll(inBackground: [myPFFile1, myPFFile2], block: { result, error in

    })

    PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground({ result, error in

        if let objects = result as? [PFObject], let first = objects.first, let thumbnail = first["thumbnail"] as? PFFile {
            //can do something with thumbnail
        }
    })
```

Comment: I'm using a parse server with heroku, mongodb. Would your solution still work

Comment: Yes, I use the same setup in many projects.  Give it a try and let me know if you have questions about the solution I proposed.

Comment: Hey frankie can I ask you a question. What if I have other fieldnames that I'd like to save along with the array of images. What would I do then.

Comment: Hey Frankie what do u think

Comment: Do you think it's possible to save other fields along with the array of images. And if so. How would I do that

Comment: Of course.  Each PFObject can hold as multiple fields.  It's really just a dictionary.  So one field might be 'image' where you assign the actual PFFile.  Another field might be "name' or 'imageType' where you can assign your own values.

Comment: Hey Frankie I have a problem. Do you mind helping me.

Comment: I gave a quick example.  Also try codementor.io for real time assistance.

Comment: Hey Frankie, I have a mosaic app and a person takes a picture of certain size and depending on that size that big image is broken down into smaller ones. That's what I'm saving to parse a uiimagrarray. From your example I have to access and save each image from the array. Is there a way to save the array as a whole and not save each individual image

Comment: What do you think Frankie

Comment: The method in the example above `PFObject.saveAll(inBackground:)` does save a whole array.  You could associate each `PFFIle` to a `PFObject` called 'Tile' and then put all the 'Tiles' into an array and associate them to another `PFObject` called 'image'.  That would help organize your data model.

Comment: I thank you for all your help but i have one problem that's not being addressed. I have a mosaic app that bis take down an image into small images. Depending on the image size, different amounts of smaller images can be produced. I have an array with different amounts of images in it each time. So there isn't a set amount of images like the example you have above that declares image 1 as pffile1 and image 2 as pffile2. Can you change to show me how I can access all the images from the array if there are different numbers of pffiles each time

Comment: This sounds different than the original question, if you can ask in a new question with examples of what you're trying to do and what you've tried let me know the link.

Comment: Sure, I'm at work right now and I'll do it at 3:30. Can you please look at it at 4:00 because I really need to fix this today.

Comment: Here is the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587944/parse-array-images-saving-and-fetching. Can you please comment and express an answer that best fits that situation. Thanks

Comment: What do you think