# Parse array images saving and fetching

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a mosaic app that takes multiple size photos and breaks them into smaller photos. Depending on the size of the photo, the amount of smaller photos could vary. Now I have an `NSMutableArray` named `imageNameList2` that holds all of the smaller images taken from the larger image. For this example I showed an example with the images being called from the image assets list to make it easier to answer this question.

Here is the `imageNameList` (`NSMutableArray` that holds all the smaller images)

```
var imageNameList: [String] {
    var imageNameList2:[String] = [] //[NSMutableArray]()
    for i in 0...149 {
        let imageName = String(format: "pic_%03d", Int(i))
        imageNameList2.append(imageName)
    }
    return imageNameList2
}
```

What I'd like to do is have a continue button that will save all these images in order as piffles or any other format to parse that works best and have another button called retrieve that will retrieve all these photos from parse. I basically have a parse server that utilizes parse frameworks to help speed up the backend process. Can you please show me how I would save and retrieve this `NSMutableArray` if there are different numbers of stored images each time?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you show your code?

Comment: I don't know where to even begin i know to how save a regular image but not an nsmutablearray of images

Comment: I'm trying to save imageNameList

Comment: Save them as what and where in what language?  When in fact there are already so many topics asking how to save images as JPEG or PNG files, why do we need another topic in the same nature?

Comment: I'm saving them as piffles using parse frameworks

Comment: each image has to be changed to UIImageJPEGRepresentation and then saved as pffiles to my parse server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this.  This is just an example. There's a lot of work to be done but hopefully this will get you started.  I did not run or test this code.

The idea is to save your images as `PFFiles`, and create a 'tile' `PFObject` for each file.  Then save all the 'tile' `PFObject`s to a 'tiles' key of the image `PFObject`.  Then recall the image when you need it by `objectId`.

Good luck.

```
let appleTiles = ["apple1, apple2, apple3"]
let orangeTiles = ["orange1, orange2, orange3, orange4, orange5"]

func usage() {

    //dont literally run these synchronously like this
    post(appleTiles)
    post(orangeTiles)
    download()
}

func post(_ tileNames: [String]) {

    let image = PFObject(className: "Image")

    let tilesPF = tileNames.map({ name in
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: name))!
        let file = PFFile(data: data)

        let tile = PFObject(className: "Tile")
        tile["tile"] = file
    })

    image["tiles"] = tilesPF

    image?.saveInBackground(block: { responseObject, error in

        //you'll want to save the object ID of the PFObject if you want to retrieve a specific image later
    })
}

func download() {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "image")

    //add this if you have a specific image you want to get
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "someObjectId")

    query.findObjectsInBackground({ result, error in

        //this is probably close to how you'd unwrap everything but again, I didn't test it so...
        if let objects = result as? [PFObject], let first = objects.first, let image = first["image"] as? PFObject, let tiles = image["tiles"] as? [PFObject] {

            tiles.forEach({ tile in

                let file = tile["tile"]

                //now you have an individual PFFile for a tile, do something with it
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but I get a thread breakpoint crash. At                       let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tile as! UIImage)!

Comment: I'm getting an error at UIImagePNGRepresentation(tile)! of "cannot convert type pffobject to type uiimage"

Comment: Well I just typed this code as an example without testing it so you're going to need to know how to use it and understand what error messages are telling you.  I forgot to add a line to turn 'tile', the image name, into an actual image.  I'll add that line now.

Comment: Alright Frankie I have three options and I was wondering if I could get your opinion one which one would be the fastest. One is to use a for loop alongside your code to save the images. The next is to convert each image into base64 string and then reconvert it into an image.

Comment: What's quicker, saving 150 jpeg to parse at .75 resolution or converting 150 images to base64 string and saving the string to parse and then retrieving the string and comverting that string back to an image

Comment: I don't know, you're going to have to do some more research and ask separate questions on SO to see if others can help you.  You can also implement your different options and see which one is the fastest for yourself.

Comment: Do I add a pointer to each individual tile and bring it back to the whole posting